# Kubernetes - Vagrant and NodePort

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes

I'm trying to run the `kubernetes guestbook` app on Vagrant on my local Mac OS X machine.

I have all the nodes (master and node-1) running, by running the following:

`./kubectl.sh create -f ../examples/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml`

As I'm running locally, I also changed the about yaml file, to use `NodePort` instead of `LoadBalancer`

Running the following:

`./kubectl.sh describe service frontend` returns the following:

```
Name:           frontend
Labels:         app=guestbook,tier=frontend
Selector:       app=guestbook,tier=frontend
Type:           NodePort
IP:         10.247.127.146
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   31030/TCP
Endpoints:      10.246.9.12:80,10.246.9.13:80,10.246.9.7:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

If I try: `http://10.247.127.146:31030` It doesn't conenct to the guestbook app.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodePort is the port available on every kubernetes node.

You need to find the IP address of your kubernetes node, and then `http://<nodeIP>:31030` should work.